# R: Classes of specific columns in list of dataframes

Tags: r, excel, lapply

I have a set of excel files each containing one sheet of data, all of similar structure (mostly -- see below), that I want to ultimately combine into one large data frame (with each sub-set indexed by original file source).
I am able to create a list of multiple dataframes, and then merge these into one dataframe, pretty easily with the following code:

```
files <- grep(".xlsx", dir(), value=TRUE) # vector of file names
IDnos <- substr(files,20,24) #vector with key 5-digit ID info of each file

library("XLConnect")
library("data.table")

datalist <- lapply(files, readWorksheetFromFile, sheet = "Data")
names(datalist) <- IDnos
bigdatatable <- rbindlist(datalist, idcol = "IDNo")
```

One data column "Value" is usually class numeric, except I found that in several there was an "ND" put in to one row, making it class character, so in the final data frame the column is character.

Although I can fix this with some simple cleaning, I was left wondering if there is way to identify at the "list of dataframes" stage which files (or dataframe components of the list I created) with class character for column "Value".  For example I can't run sapply(datalist,class) or other variations.  I am hoping to avoid a for-loop.

Is there any way to use lapply or sapply to drill down into dataframes within a list?

Comment: What does `ND` mean? A missing value? If so, then you need to identify them as such with `na.strings="ND"` ... if `readWorksheetFromFile` has that argument.

Comment: You might also consider the `readxl` package. The function `read_excel` takes arguments `col_types = ` for guessing/setting column class and `na = `, which you could set to "ND" if that is the sole missing value indicator.

Comment: Rich, unfortunately I don't see the na/na.strings functionality in the XLConnect package.  Neil, the readxl does work nicely in this way.  However, I'm still wondering how to use lapply/sapply or something similar on a list of dataframes to do things to columns in each dataframe.

Comment: Like you do now, just write (an anonymous) function. `sapply(yourdata, FUN = function(x) {your code of manipulating the data})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would use `lapply` to find the class of column `a` in a list of 2 data frames, named `x` and `y`.

```
datalist <- list(x = data.frame(a = letters),
                 y = data.frame(a = 1:26))
lapply(datalist, function(x) class(x$a))

$x
[1] "factor"

$y
[1] "integer"
```

Comment: Thank you!  Exactly what I was looking for!